# Deploy vs Import Datatier application in SSMS what's the difference

Tags: sql-server, ssms

What's the difference between Deploy vs Import Datatier application in SSMS?

Answer (score 1):

deploy requires a dacpac file and import requires a bacpac file.  I think the former is just schema and code, the latter has schema, code and data.